# Is it possible to store model data as xml?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I am playing with writing an asp.net mvc4 application in C#.

I've used databases to store model data in the past, but I was wondering if I could have my model data stored as xml instead.

Does anyone know if this is possible or how to do it?

Comment: It's usually called serialization. [Link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815813), [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/455861/Serialize-Deserialize-any-object-to-an-XML-file).

Answer (score 2):

Yes [Persistence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistence_%28computer_science%29) is available in many forms.  This is possible with [Serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4abbf6k0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). More specifically [XmlSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). .NET has strong support for XML serialization.   You can take a class and decorate it with the SerializeableAttribute

```
[Serializeable]
public class MyClass {}
```